# SNMP4J.jar - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jar, snmp, snmp4j

I'm trying to check some `SNMP` example, so

- i've downloaded `snmp4j.jar`
- compiled `SNMP.java` using `javac -cp snmp4j.jar SNMP.java` (it's OK)
- tried to start it using `java -cp snmp4j.jar SNMP`, but

it reports:

```
root@comp:~/workspace_c/SNMP# java -cp snmp4j.jar SNMP
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SNMP
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SNMP
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: SNMP.  Program will exit.
```

**UPDATE:** 
And when I import `snmp4j.jar` to the java project, it works normally in `ECLIPSE`...

**UPDATE@2:** main part of `SNMP.java`

```
import org.snmp4j.CommunityTarget;
...
public class SNMP {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
  }
}
```

what i'm doing wrong? it's first time i've met `snmp4j` so i know noting about it

Comment: Is the class `SNMP` part of some package ? (does it have a `package` statement inside ?) This may be reason you get that error.

Comment: No, it isn't.... :/ snmp4j.jar and also SNMP.java are in one folder, SNMP.java is without package statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `SNMP` is your example class, which isn't inside the jar. In that case, you need to add to the classpath both the jar and your current directory:

```
java -cp .:snmp4j.jar SNMP
```

Comment: No, SNMP.java is separeted class which is using methods from snmp4j.jar

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. Please try the command line I suggested and tell us if it works.

Comment: aha "which ISN'T inside", it really works! thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are trying to run your application with `SNMP4J.jar` (upper case) but when you compiled your application you probably used lower case version. 
Your prompt shows that your are using unix OS that has case sensitive file system. So, check the case of the JAR file name. I believe that all letters are in lower case.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I've merged two my attepts - problem is not in case sensitive linux enviroment. I've updated my question.. sorry again :(